# Intercept a4j:commandButton request

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am developing web application using A4J, Richfaces.
One of my requirement is, I need to check if the user has changed any values in the form when he is trying navigate away from the page.

I have save and cancel buttons in the page.
I am using `a4j:command` button for cancel functionality. Clicking on cancel button should do below things

1. Check if the user has modified anything in the form (this I am doing by using javascript and have a flag if user changed any values)
2. Display confirmation box (javascript confirm with values "Do you really want to discard the changes -- YES NO") when user changes form values
3. If user says YES, then submit the form using AJAX (by using A4J)

My a4j command button code is like this

```
<a4j:commandButton action="MyClass.cancel_action"
    onclick="checkIsPageChanged()"/>
```

The issue here is, while using using `a4j:commandButton`, I cannot call the intermediate javascript function (the function which checks if user has updated any values and displays confirmation box) and then submit the request using ajax.
I have looked at the code generated by JSF and the code is like (not the exact but syntact)

```
<input type="button"
    onclick="checkIsPageChanged();AJAX.submit('')/>
```

The thing is when I click on button, it is calling only `checkIsPageChanged()` and not calling `AJAX.submit()`.

Any workaround for this will help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be more specific we can use:

```
onclick="if(!isPageChanged()) {return false}"
```

Returning false will not submit the request.

Comment: Your code works, but it should be clarified that returning `true` will also not submit the request. See https://community.jboss.org/thread/3755?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t
In effect, `onclick="!isPageChanged()"` will _not_ work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `a4j:jsFunction` and call that from your `a4j:commandButton` when the `checkIsPageChanged()` returns true.

eg.

```
<a4j:commandButton action="MyClass.cancel_action"
    onclick="if(checkIsPageChanged()) { cancel(); }"/>
<a4j:jsFunction name="cancel" action="MyClass.cancel_action"/>
```